# Select certain attributes from a document in mongodb using mongoose for dynamic referencing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, select

Is it possible to select certain attributes from an object? for example excluding an email, logoUri...etc and personal info from a seller when populating dynamically?

Here is my messageSchema:

```
const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  chatId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Chat",
  },
   ....
  // sender can be type of User or Seller
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: "senderType",
    required: true,
  },
  senderType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["User", "Seller"],
  },
  readOn: { type: Date },
  read: Boolean, //}, {
  sentOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

here is where I populate my schema:

```
const messages = await Message.find({ chatId: chatId })
      .populate("sender")
      .sort({
        sentOn: -1,
      });
```

since each has different attribute, is there a way to select depending on the type of model I am populating dynamically ? For example for user model:

```
.select('-email -logoUri')
```

for seller model:

```
.select('-address')
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `.populate('sender', '-email -logoUri -address')`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to set up use cases with selectors for each model the case is for

```js
messageSelectors = {
  user: "-email -logoUri",
  seller: "-address",
  ...
}
```

Then, whenever you need to use selectors for messages, you can use selectors based on what your selecting for

```js
function selectMessageAttributesFor(type, query){
  //verify type is in messageSelectors
  selected = await Messages.find(query).select(messageSelectors[type]).exec(callback);
}
```